# Why is my object missing in the render?

Tags: rendering

I recently rendered a project i was working on and found that the main object was missing in the final render. I checked older versions of the file and it was all the same. What could it be?[image]

the render is on the right.[image]

this is the most recent state. There are some pyramids on top. I wondered if it has something to do with textures i added, but i removed them and nothing changed.
[image]
this is an older version, before i tinkered with textures...

Comment: It appears that many objects in your outliner are disabled for render. That is a very likely cause.

Comment: thanks! i din´t realize you can enable and disable objects in the outliner. That was it!